# Can we transform clauses to participle clauses when they appear in question-form sentences?

Tags: grammar, participle-clauses

We know the clauses in bold (01 and 02) can be reduced to participle clauses because the subjects of the subordinate clauses are the same as those of the main clauses:

**01**

> We saw lots of lanterns **when we walked on the streets**.

transformed to

> We saw lots of lanterns **when walking on the streets**.

**02**

> We learn new facts **because we go to school**.

transformed to

> We learn new facts **because going to school**.

---

Questions:

How about in a question form?

Can I transform the below clauses to participle clauses?

Are they grammatically correct?

03

> Can we tell him the truth **when we talk to him**?

> Can we tell him the truth **when talking to him**?

04

> Are we allowed to scold someone **because we hate them**?

> Are we allowed to scold someone **because hating them**?

Comment: The second sentence of 02 isn't correct. Similarly, second sentence of 04 isn't correct either.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh  You mean a participle clause can be formed in a question-form sentence but the use of  "because" is just not correct being used like that? Would you shed light on this topic?

Comment: The conjunction 'because' isn't usually used with the present participle following right behind it. It is more suited with the simple present (base) form of the verb. If you wish to use present participle, you need to restructure your sentence something like: _Are we allowed to scold someone because of hating them?_ However, inserting 'of' wouldn't sound any good for the second sentence of 02. _We learn new facts because we go to school._ This is indicating a habitual action. Hence usage of present participle is unidiomatic for the most part.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Thank you. I found source that says conjunctions such as because or since are not shown when they are used in a participle clause. The link is https://english.lingolia.com/en/grammar/sentences/participle-clauses. However, what I am concerned about is whether a interrogative sentence affects the use of participle clause. Would you answer that? Thank you.